# How to draw this complex figure

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to draw the curve $C$ of $z(t)$ where $C$ design $|z|=1,y \geq 0$ ,and $\sqrt{1}=-1$

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt{1}=-1$?

Answer (score 2):

Start with $z=x+iy$
$$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1 \\ \implies x^2+y^2=1;y\ge0$$

The shape is a semicircle on the positive side of y.